# Rewrite in .htaccess wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, wpml

I have this url right now:

```
www.mywebsite.com/pt-br/index
```

But I need to change for:

```
www.mywebsite.com/pt/index
```

Is that possible using .htaccess? I use WPML plugin in wordpress for languages.

Thanks!

Sorry for my english, i'm from Argentina!

My actual htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /labs/test-carrito/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /labs/test-carrito/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please post your htaccess rule file in your question for better understanding of your question, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The language code in the URL is controlled by the "code" selection within your language that you can see from WPML->Languages->Edit languages

https://wpml.org/forums/topic/change-language-code-for-urls/

Comment: Thanks! but is not possible to change "code", and i need to change that without delete the language. For that reason i look make it with htaccess.

Comment: I think the only option is as described in the article. The way you would achieve this is adding regular portugese as a language, and change the Default locale to pt_BR and hreflang to pt-br, dont forget to select a custom flag if you want to show the brazilian flag instead of the portugese. before you can do this you have to append _old to the brazillian local and herf language. after that change the language of all the pase/posts etc from brazillian to portugese one.

Comment: unfortunately i can't add a new language. My only option is work with htaccess!